# In new Laravel prompt installation with Breeze livewire app, how to add alpinejs plugin?

Tags: laravel-livewire

In the new Laravel prompt installation with the Breeze livewire app, how to add the Alpinejs plugin? because already breeze installed livewire and Alpinejs with auto-injection assets, when I want to add a new Alpinejs plugin in app.js I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found I must use Alpinejs in Livewire Component.